# Parsing xml attribute using XPath in Mule

Tags: xml, xpath, mule

My mule application receives xml as payload. There is an attribute present in the beginning of the xml in its root element. I need to retreive it to make a choice statement. I am using the xpath3 parser. But I am unable to do it. My xml looks like this -:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1"?>
<DeliveryMessage DeliveryMessageType="XXX" DeliveryMessageStatusType="YYY"
 xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="zzz.xsd">
```

I have tried this -:

```
set-variable variableName="check" value="#[xpath3('/DeliveryMessage/@DeliveryMessageType').text,payload,String]" doc:name="Variable"/>
```

But I am not receiving any value. It is showing null. My xml file comes as a payload through a SFTP endpoint.

I need the value of xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation.

Comment: Hi @Arup. Is that you complete XML payload? -------------------------------------------
<DeliveryMessage DeliveryMessageType="XXX" DeliveryMessageStatusType="YYY"
 xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="zzz.xsd"> ---- should it end with /> ?

Comment: No its not the complete payload. But the above part is relevant to me, from which I need the value of xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation

Comment: Ok I get it, use the namespace manager so you could map the xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation. See this link: https://docs.mulesoft.com/mule-user-guide/v/3.7/xml-namespaces

Comment: @ArupMishra if you need xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation, why are you retrieving DeliveryMessageStatusType attribute

Answer (score 0):

```
#[xpath3('//DeliveryMessage/@DeliveryMessageType')]
```

Note the 2 forward slash in front of DeliveryMessage not 1

By default, 2nd and 3rd parameter of `xpath3()` function are `payload` and STRING` so that's optional

Answer (score -1):

based from these links:

https://docs.mulesoft.com/mule-user-guide/v/3.7/xpath
http://blogs.mulesoft.com/dev/mule-dev/mule-3-6-xml-xpath-xslt-xquery3/

It should be `#[xpath3('/DeliveryMessage/@DeliveryMessageType',payload,STRING)]`